# Have a variable exist in all functions of a class?

Tags: php

I have a small problem - I want to decrease code duplication in my site, and the best way that I can see of doing that is to remove a lot of unnecessary instances of variable setting.

One of the most common is the $baseUrl variable, which contains the http host and php self values, for convenience. However, I have to set it for each function:

```
class Site
{
function outputPage()
{    
$baseUrl = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
}
}
```

This is then typically included in any links that the site uses:

```
echo '<a href="' . $baseUrl .'/article/jun/example11/">Example 11</a>';
```

It's set around six times throughout the class, once per function that needs it - is there any way to set it *once* and then allow all the functions to access it?

Comment: is there a reason you're using absolute URLs like that instead of relative ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set it as a class variable, and initialize it in the constructor :

```
class Site {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->baseUrl = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        var_dump('constructor : ' . $this->baseUrl);
    }
    function outputPage() {    
        // use $this->baseUrl
        var_dump($this->baseUrl);
    }
    protected $baseUrl;
}
```

And, then, when using the class :

```
$a = new Site();
$a->outputPage();
```

You'll get :

```
string 'constructor : http://tests/temp' (length=31)
string 'http://tests/temp' (length=17)
```

In some cases, you could also initialize "on the fly" when you're declaring it (on the line with protected, in my example).

But this doesn't work with everything ; you can't call a function there, for instance, if I remember correctly ; you can't concatenate strings either :

```
class Site {
    function outputPage() {    
        // use $this->baseUrl
        var_dump($this->baseUrl);
    }
    protected $baseUrl = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
}
```

Would give you this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'
```

But this :

```
class Site {
    function outputPage() {    
        // use $this->baseUrl
        var_dump($this->baseUrl);
    }
    protected $baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Would work -- but it's not as powerful, and you can't really do whatever you might want, this way...

Answer (score 5):

Methods of a class can access members of that class.

```
class Site {

  private $baseurl;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->baseurl = "http://www.somesite.com";
  }

  public function hello()
  {
    print "My baseurl is " . $this->baseurl;
  }

}

$site = new Site;
$site->hello(); // My baseurl is http://www.somesite.com
```

Comment: He can't use concatenations or variables outside of methods.

Comment: What? Where did he say he can't use concat or variables?

Comment: No. He doesn't need to concat. There are many ways to build a string without using .

Comment: For your example to apply to his set up, he would have to use variables and concat in place of your somesite.com variable, and concating outside of a method is illegal.

Comment: The value of `private $baseurl` must be static. Per documentation : http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

just create a class member with that variable :)

```
class Site {
  private $baseurl;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->baseurl = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
  }
  public function outputPage() {    
    echo $this->baseurl;
  }
}
```

Comment: This will get a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'" : you cannont concatenate strings outside of a method.

Comment: You can't use variables or functions as well.

Comment: good catch, i was too fast writing my answer. fixed using a constructor

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a constant for it:

```
define("BASE_URL", "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\'));
```

Then use

```
echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL .'/article/jun/example11/">Example 11</a>';
```

It is appropriate to use a constant because the value never changes in the run time of the script. You could also set a class variable for it. Which still will have to be duplicated in every class.

```
class myClass{
    private $baseURL;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->baseURL = http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
    }
    function speak()
    {
        echo $this->baseURL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to define those sorts of things as class constants.

```
class Settings
{
    const BASE_URL = "http://google.com";
}
```

Then you can use `require_once("settings.php");` anywhere and have access to `Settings::Base_URL`

Comment: Oh, looks like you need some computation. You can declare it as a variable instead of a const `public BASE_URL` and then compute it at the top of the file