# Variable in php class which can be used in all its functions

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, scope, codeigniter-2

I want to declare a variable in a php class which can be used in all its functions. I am using the codeigniter framework & to have to pass data like base_url etc in each of the functions. Also I need all of such data in a single variable. For example `$data['base_url']=base_url()`, `$data['title']="My_Site_title"` etc & then send only a single variable $data (this is a common thing in codeigniter).

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274186/have-a-variable-exist-in-all-functions-of-a-class) question, I modified my code to:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller {

function Search() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('student_model');

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

    $this->data['base_url']=base_url();  //gives an error here
 }

 function index() {
     $this->load->view('search_view', $this->data);
 }
 }
```

But still it gives an error at the marked place saying `Undefined variable: data` and `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in ..\search.php on line 16`.

Comment: can't use $data without instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller {

protected $data = array();

function Search() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('student_model');

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

    $this->data['base_url']=base_url();
 }

 function index() {
     $this->load->view('search_view', $this->data);
 }
 }
```

More about class properties in php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php